# KVO Swift: newValue is always nil

Tags: swift, key-value-observing, objective-c-runtime

Having the following example:

```
import UIKit

@objc class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @objc dynamic var buggyApple: NSObject?

    var obs: NSKeyValueObservation?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        obs = observe(\.buggyApple, changeHandler: { (obj, change) in
            print(change)
        })
        buggyApple = NSObject()
        buggyApple = NSObject()
    }
}
```

I get the corresponding output in the debug console:

```
NSKeyValueObservedChange<Optional<NSObject>>(kind: __C.NSKeyValueChange, newValue: Optional(nil), oldValue: Optional(nil), indexes: nil, isPrior: false)
NSKeyValueObservedChange<Optional<NSObject>>(kind: __C.NSKeyValueChange, newValue: Optional(nil), oldValue: Optional(nil), indexes: nil, isPrior: false)
```

While inspecting the `ViewController` object on breakpoint inside the callback in the `LLDB`, I get the following:

```
(lldb) po obj.buggyApple
▿ Optional<NSObject>
  - some : <NSObject: 0x600000908fa0>
```

So, in fact, the new `NSObject` has been successfully sent, however, the `change` is still references `nil`. Is there any problem in my code and how to fix it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to supply the `new` option to the `options` input argument of the `observer` method to receive the new value in `change`.

```
obs = observe(\.buggyApple, options: [.new], changeHandler: { (obj, change) in
    print(change)
})
```

Comment: Thanks!  Works like the classic KVO in Objective-C. Seems that by default it just tracks the fact of the change, not providing the old/new values.

Comment: Worth noting that Apple suggests NOT using `.new`, but rather just read the current value from the observed object.

Comment: @OscarApeland please, point to a link where I could read that more in detail. Thanks.

Comment: @RichardTopchiy have a look at [Using Key-Value Observing in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/cocoa_design_patterns/using_key-value_observing_in_swift)

Comment: @DávidPásztor there is nothing about "not using `.new` and reading the current value from the observed object". Indeed, in the sample code they read it from the `.newValue` property

Comment: @RichardTopchiy From the Foundation header: "///newValue and oldValue will only be non-nil if .new/.old is passed to `observe()`. In general, get the most up to date value by accessing it directly on the observed object instead."

Comment: Strange that old and new values are passed despite the recommendation not to use.

Comment: ps. another oddity is that obj reference is that of the observer, not the changed object.